# Quick way to solve $16x \equiv -9 \pmod {3^5}$

Tags: number-theory

Quick way to solve $16x \equiv -9=234 \pmod {3^5}$

Any hints?

I tried all the numbers from $1$ to $10$ but none work.

Comment: Have you found the inverse of $16 \pmod{243}$?

Comment: No the question is to write $\frac{-9}{16}$ in $\mathbb{Z_3}$ so I have to solve congruences $16x \equiv -9 \pmod {3^k}$

Comment: Maybe it follows from the other values so for $k=1, x=0$; $k=2,x=0$; $k=3,x=18$

Answer (score 5):

$16x\equiv 234$ and therefore $8x\equiv 117$ and therefore $8x\equiv 360$  and thefore $x\equiv 45$, all modulo $243$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:*

If $16x \equiv -9 \bmod {3^5}$, then $16x \equiv -9 \bmod {3^2}$ and so $x \equiv 0 \bmod {3^2}$.

Let $x=9y$. Then we can cancel $9$ in $16x \equiv -9 \bmod {3^5}$ and get $16y \equiv -1 \bmod {3^3}$, which is simpler.

Comment: Can you explain how you went from $x=9y$ to the last congruence?

Comment: @user230452, see my edited answer.